# svn won't accept certificate, though s_client does

Tags: svn, ssl, ssl-certificate

When running svn against our svn server I'm getting this error (domain name and fingerprint edited):

```
Error validating server certificate for 'https://svn.example.org:443':
  - The certificate has expired.
  - The certificate has an unknown error.
Certificate information:
  - Hostname: mail.example.org
  - Valid: from Fri, 24 Sep 2010 13:05:10 GMT until Wed, 09 Feb 2011
15:24:52 GMT
  - Issuer: 07969287, http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository,
GoDaddy.com, Inc., Scottsdale, Arizona, US
  - Fingerprint: 00:e5:....
(R)eject or accept (t)emporarily? t
```

So one error says it has expired, and a few lines later it says the expiry date is 2011. And then there is an unknown error. This is svn 1.6 - older versions had an accept permanently option.

I've also tried running `openssl s_client` to check the certificate:

```
openssl s_client -host svn.example.org -port 443 -verify 5 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs
```

And amongst other output I get:

```
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: zlib compression
Expansion: zlib compression
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 7604...
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 22AB...
    Key-Arg   : None
    Compression: 1 (zlib compression)
    Start Time: 1288804434
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Which suggests that SSL is set up properly.

The only thing I can think of is that we're using a multi-domain certificate, with mail.example.org being the subject CN and svn.example.org being listed in the subjectAltName section.

This is affecting a number of people, and I don't want our clients to have to deal with this, so I'd really like a solution that makes this error go away rather than just fixing it for me. Any help appreciated.

**Edit:** I can load `https://svn.example.org/` in my web browser and it doesn't complain. I can view the certificate hierarchy through the web browser and none of the certificates in the chain have expired.

I've checked `ldd svn` as suggested by Bruno, and it is linked against libgnutls, while openssl is linked against libssl. Is there an equivalent to the s_client command using libgnutls?

**Edit2:** (So it's easy to find for later people). `svn` uses the gnutls library rather than the ssl library, and gnutls is more strict than ssl. So in order to see the error, you need to use `gnutls-cli`. In my case, [gnutls didn't like the order of certificates](http://www.mail-archive.com/help-gnutls@gnu.org/msg01213.html), even though they are all there. See the link before for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will fix your problem, but there's an `ssl-authority-files` option you can configure in `~/.subversion/servers` (you can limit it to certain hosts if you want, I think).

In addition, it's possible that your version of `svn` is linked against another library than OpenSSL for its SSL/TLS stack, for example GnuTLS (this should be visible using `ldd` on the svn binary).

(Have you checked whether the CA certificate may have expired, rather than the server certificate itself?)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've added more info in the question. This affects a few people, so I'm looking for something that will fix it without everyone having to edit their config. Though it's a useful backup if nothing else will work.

Comment: Have you changed the `ssl-authority-files` configuration option? There's no real reason why `svn` should have the same set of trusted CA certificates as your browser by default, which may explain why it works in the browser and not in svn.

Comment: Ah, got nearer - I found the `gnutls-cli` client. This does complain in the same way as `svn`. It appears to be something to do with the [order of certificates](http://www.mail-archive.com/help-gnutls@gnu.org/msg01213.html). I'll see if I can fix that, and if not I'll be off to serverfault ...